# Automatic splitting of long Tailwind strings in VSCode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm looking for a neat way to split this Mississippi River:

```js
<input
  value={props.profile.get('email') ?? ''}
  placeholder="Email Address"
  className="z-10 flex-shrink-0 w-12 h-12 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-[5px] focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border focus:border-indigo-400 hover:outline-none hover:ring-[5px] hover:ring-indigo-100 hover:border hover:border-indigo-200 transform-gpu transition-all duration-50"
  onChange={e => props.updateProfile('email', e.currentTarget.value)}
/>
```

into something more digestible when scrolling through big repos.
Currently I'm using this approach for splitting strings:

```js
<input
  value={props.profile.get('email') ?? ''}
  placeholder="Email Address"
  className={classNames(
    "z-10 block w-full h-12 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-300",
    "focus:outline-none focus:ring-[5px] focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border focus:border-indigo-400",
    "hover:outline-none hover:ring-[5px] hover:ring-indigo-100 hover:border hover:border-indigo-200",
    "transform-gpu transition-all duration-50",
  )}
  onChange={e => props.updateProfile('email', e.currentTarget.value)}
/>
```

But there should be more convenient way, so how do you handle long rules, fellow Tailwinders?

Answer (score 0):

The only way out of this is using [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro), but even then the long rules will be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bundle these into logical groups if I were you and put them in a common file:

`styles.js`:

```js
const form = 'block h-12 px-3 py-1 focus:outline-none focus: ....';
const button = 'rounded-lg border border-gray-300';
```

Your file then becomes:

```js
import { form, button, input, grey } from 'styles';

...
classNames(`${form} ${button} ${input} ${grey}`)
```